# Click function doesn't work on a new added class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button that adds `newClass` to the parent `div` when clicked and it also shows another button. The next thing that I want to make is to display some text with a click function on `.newClass .display-info`.

All the answers that I've found refer to the jQuery `.live` method, but this is deprecated. Instead I used `.on` method but without any result...

This is the example code:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBfMV/636/)

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn-click">
    Click me
  </button>

  <button class="display-info">
    Show text
  </button>
  <span class="show-this">Text to be displayed</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.btn-click').click(function() {
    $(".parent").addClass('newClass');
  $(".display-info").show();
});

$('.newClass .display-info').on("click",function() {
    $('.show-this').show();
});
```

CSS:

```
.display-info, .show-this {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: RTFM... Here we go: http://api.jquery.com/on/  And here for some explaination https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always prefer on method relating to document.

inplace of this

```
$('.newClass .display-info').on("click",function() {
    $('.show-this').show();
});
```

do like below

```
$(document).on("click",".newClass .display-info",function() {
    $('.show-this').show();
});
```

Comment: Your selector will not work ;)

Comment: Thank you, this works for me!

Comment: that is good. now as you can see mod has marked this question as duplicate so please go through previosu question attached by him to check all the detail why we should use ON and how because in that question answer is very detailed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.btn-click').click(function() {
  $(".parent").addClass('newClass');
  $(".display-info").show();
  $('.newClass .display-info').on("click",function() {
     $('.show-this').show();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using

```
$('.btn-click').click()
```

It will work only for static dom, but you are providing a class dynamically that's why it is not working. So for dynamic content always use on() jquery